# Any tricks to fix this syntax error in PLPGSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am creating a function to add roles. This function receives two arguments: name and a list of functions that can be executed from the role.

I am having trouble assigning the content of the v_execute argument inside the statement: `GRANT EXECUTE on FUNCTION i to v_rolename;`

The problem is that EXECUTE on FUNCTION expects a function name like this: `fn_customer_add()` and I am passing an array type variable there.

This is my plpgsql code:

```
    create function fn_roles_add(v_role_name varchar, v_execute varchar[]) returns character varying
        language plpgsql
    as
    $$
    DECLARE
        i varchar;
        BEGIN
            CREATE ROLE v_role_name;
            /* Function execution permissions are assigned from the array argument v_role_name */
            FOREACH i IN ARRAY v_execute
            LOOP
               GRANT EXECUTE on FUNCTION i to v_role_name;
            END LOOP;
        RETURN 'OK';
        END;
    $$;
```

If I replace `v_execute[i]` with the name of an existing function, it works correctly. But I need to be able to pass it a variable number of functions since my database is based on using functions for almost all queries.

Error:

*[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "to"*

**Does anyone have any ideas to trick plpgsql in order to perform this action?**

Comment: `v_rolename` vs. `v_role_name` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, sorry they are the same, my mistake during the writing, but it does not solve it.

Comment: Might want to edit the question to clear that up for others, I'm not a postgres guru by any means.

Comment: I already did, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables as identifiers (column or table names). You need dynamic SQL for this:

```
execute format('CREATE ROLE %I', v_role_name);
```

and

```
execute format('GRANT EXECUTE on FUNCTION %I to %I', i, v_role_name);
```

Comment: Great, but I had to replace the first type %I with %s , because when I used type %I Postgres added quotes to the string and didn't recognize the function. I was struggling with it until I realized what the problem was. If anyone knows why this happens with %I I would appreciate commenting.

Comment: @GonzaloAmadorDemeneghi: `%I` properly deals with Identifiers. I overlooked that, `i` isn't an integer, but actually a "name"